# Windows confused about position of monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell Optiplex 980 machine. Two monitors (17 in. and 22 in.) are attached to it. The smaller one was attached from begning, later on I added the larger one. The smaller one on left as primary monitor and larger one on right as secondary monitor (with desktop extended on both monitors).

Yesterday I re-organized my workspace and I have to move larger one on the left. I set the large monitor as primary in Display Properties dialog. It is fine with only glitch that I have to take my mouse cursor on the smaller monitor from left edge of the larger (primary) monitor.

I tried by inter-changing the connecting cables but Windows 7 still refuses to believe that larger monitor is on the left and smaller one on the right side.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the panel where you set which monitor is primary, just drag them into their correct positions.